# Can't run systrace as root

Tags: android, adb, systrace

I'm trying to get systrace to provide disk output.

I've rooted my device and I'm able to switch to superuser in adb shell just fine.

```
python systrace.py -d -o ~/systrace1.html
```

produces

```
'error: tracing disk activity requires root privileges'
```

If I try to restart adb with root privileges by running

```
adb root
```

I get

```
'adbd cannot run as root in production builds'
```

It may be that I'm just not understanding what's meant by "production builds".
Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [adb sources](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/jb-mr2-release/adb/services.c) do this:

```
    property_get("ro.debuggable", value, "");
    if (strcmp(value, "1") != 0) {
        snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "adbd cannot run as root in production builds\n");
```

In other words, if it doesn't see `ro.debuggable` set to 1 it won't let you run `adb root`.  Check the contents of your `/default.prop`.

Comment: Thanks, I suspect this is the correct answer. Is there a way to set ro.debuggable to 1? setprop 1 doesn't seem to stick even when I run the command as su.

Comment: The "ro." means "read-only".  Once set, it cannot be altered.  The way you change it is to edit the property file that sets it (should be `/default.prop`) and reboot.

Comment: So to be able to edit the property file I had to remount the file system rw (http://android-tricks.blogspot.com/2009/01/mount-filesystem-read-write.html) and change permissions on the default.prop file. 'cat default.prop' now shows ro.debuggable=1 but getprop still shows ro.debuggable 0. How should I re-initialize that property? Stopping and then starting the shell doesn't seem to be enough. Rebooting seems to overwrite my changes.

Comment: Accepting answer. I suspect this will work for others. I'm not sure why the default.prop file is being overwritten on my ASUS Transformer.

Comment: Best guess: it's being loaded from the "boot" partition into a RAM disk at startup, so every time you reboot it resets.  If so, you will need to flash a new boot image (`fastboot flash boot <file.img>`).  Easy enough from a full source tree (edit the default.prop and rebuild; image is `out/target/product/<target>/boot.img), not sure what to do otherwise.  Note that "boot" is not the same as "bootloader".